# Powerpoint - Playing a bunch of images automatically, as a movie

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

If I have a series of images that I want to play in powerpoint, in a single slide (as opposed to copy each image in a separate slide) what is the best way to do it? 
Is there a straightforward way to make them a GIF picture or a similar format?
I don't want to create a video because I'm afraid it's going to be much heavier, while all I want is just a bunch of images automatically playing.

Comment: What research have you done on making a GIF? What have you tried? Why do they have to be on the same slide? Is there a reason not to put each on a slide and loop thru those?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. Create a GIF. You can use an online tool for that, just google "gif creator" or something similar. High loss of quality and limited control on the final result, but fairly simple.
2. Put all the images in the same slide and use animations and timing to have them appear & disappear accordingly. Quite the hassle to set up and maintain (with many images, not that difficult with a few), but fine-grained control over the final result.
3. Actually create a video. If you remove the soundtrack, not very heavier than multiple images, especially with good compression. Very fine-grained control over the result, easier than using PowerPoint animations. However, you still have to make the video.

Personnally, I used option 2 when I had to do something like that, because I only had a few images and was too lazy to get a GIF/video making software/website.

Comment: Yeah I didn't like loss of quality with GIF, that's why I thought there must be a simple and elegant way to do it. It seems I was wrong!

Comment: The most elegant one is a video, the least elegant but with no quality loss is using PowerPoint animations and animation timings. If you only have a few pics, the latter is still manageable (I used this solution once).

Comment: Video has its advantages and disadvantages.  On the down side, once it's created, you can't edit it (ie, add/remove photos).  If all that changes is the pictures, why mess with animation at all.  Put each photo on a separate slide, set the transition effects/timing to whatever works and you're done. FAR simpler to maintain than a single slide with lots of animated photos.